# Unable to detect beacon in the background using altbeacon library on android

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

My use case is very simple all I want is to detect my beacons with given UID when the user comes close to the beacon.
The app should look for beacons every 60 sec in the background.

I am targeting android marshmallow and above so for that I am making sure location is on from setting and runtime permission for fine location is also included.

Using the below code I detect beacon in the background at a very inconsistent basis and not every 60 sec.

This is the code that I am using to detect beacons :-

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "radbeacon";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        scanBeacons();
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        // Don't care
    }

    private void scanBeacons()
    {
        RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
        BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
        BeaconManager beaconManager;
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
        Identifier identifier = Identifier.parse("0xe2bfcc3cc2370789caef");
        Region region = new Region("my-beacon-region",identifier,null,null);

        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(60000L);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2000L);


        try
        {
            beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        }
        catch (RemoteException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this,region);
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    }
}
```

What changes do I need to make to the existing code to get the required functionality? Thanks.

Comment: What is the advertising rate of your beacon?  Since you are monitoring not ranging, you only expect one detection per encounter yes?  How long does it typically take?  And is the behavior different with the app in the foreground?

Comment: Don't know where to find that. If that means calibrated power then it is -20.

Comment: I have 2 beacons both with same namespace id but different instance id(1 and 2). If i go near to the beacon with instance id = 1 then I will get notification that beacon 1 is found, next time if I go close to the same beacon then i should not get any notification. I will get notification again from beacon with instance id = 1 if only after getting notification from  beacon with instance id = 2 when i go near it.